# JQ: How to add literal value to output

Tags: json, jq

Thank you for looking at this with me.

I am using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to manipulate JSON files.

Started with this that works:

```
jq ".[]|{name:.name,type:.type}" r.json
```

Need to extent to include "acct" and a literal value of "acct1" into the resulting json.

I know I can do it with **two** lines of code

```
jq '.[]+{acct:"acct1"}' r.json > r2.json
jq "{acct:.acct,name:.name,type:.type}" r2.json > r.json
```

Is there a way to do it inline with **one** line of code - like this which is not working ?

```
jq '.[]|{acct:"acct1",name:.name,type:.type}' r.json
```

Thank you for looking at this problem

Comment: jq and jmespath are different languages/tools. Seems like you're using jq - you might want to change this question a little (and use the jq website for reference!).

Comment: I removed jmespath from the problem

Answer (score 1):

A more economical approach to achieving what I understand you want would be:

```
jq '.[]|{name,type, acct:"acct1"}' r.json
```

Incidentally, the first filter in the Q (`.[]|{name:.name,type:.type}`) can be abbreviated to:

```
.[]|{name,type}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for was

```
jq '.[]+{acct:"acct1"}|{acct:.acct,name:.name,type:.type}" r2.json > r.json
```

Just had to learn how |'s worked :)